# MySQL - как мне достать из БД из столбца определенное количество символов, но без тегов?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Я хочу достать, например, 300 символов. Это превью статьи. Чтобы прочитать всю статью, нужно перейти на страницу с ней (открыть ее). Проблема в том, что в БД могут в тексте использоваться теги. В php я их убираю (strip_tags). Но получается уже меньше 300 символов. Как я понял, нужно убирать их при выборке данных. Как мне это сделать? Помогите написать запрос.

Comment: выбирайте текст с большим запасом и удаляйте теги в php. На MySQL это будет слишком сложно и громоздко

Comment: может проще завести еще одно поле и при добавлении статьи вносить туда подготовленное превью ? тогда вам не придется каждый раз обрабатывать текст и выделять из него 300 символов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй "strip_tags" эквивалент на MySQL.
[тут пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654436/what-is-the-mysql-query-equivalent-of-php-strip-tags).

Далее делай выборку вида:

```
SELECT LEFT(strip_tags('text here'), 300);
```

Но вариант с обработкой этого на PHP звучит лучше.